# "revert erc20 transfer amount exceeds allowance" error with transferFrom() but not with _transfer()

Tags: solidity, erc-20, transferfrom

I confirmed that approval is accurate, yet I receive the "revert erc20 transfer amount exceeds allowance" error when using the `transferFrom()` function.  Yet for some reason the internal `_transfer()` function works without any issues.

I checked and `transferFrom()` is public, not external.

The following code results in an error:

```
    function addLiquidity(uint256 _tokenAmount) external payable onlyOwner {
        // Transfer the tokens from the sender to the contract
        // Sender should approve the contract spending the tokens
        require(allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= _tokenAmount);
        transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _tokenAmount);
    }
```

Where this works:

```
    function addLiquidity(uint256 _tokenAmount) external payable onlyOwner {
        // Transfer the tokens from the sender to the contract
        // Sender should approve the contract spending the tokens
        require(allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= _tokenAmount);
        _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), _tokenAmount);
    }
```

Note the `require` statement before each attempt to transfer that passes and therefore clearly shows the contract is allowed to transfer the tokens.

Why does `_transfer` work but `transferFrom` does not?  Shouldn't `transferFrom` work, especially considering the allowance has been correctly set?

Comment: Are you certain the `allowance` returns a valid amount? Make sure you are checking the allowance from your wallet address to this contract.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think that the `allowance` are trully set. Because `_transer` doesn't require the `allowance`anywhere. Can you share the `_transferFrom`?

Comment: The entire core ERC20 code is imported from OpenZeppelin with `import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";` (using HardHat).  I did not change `_transfer`, `transferFrom`, or `transferFrom` -- so the code is all available to be reviewed in their repositories.

The only push-back I would have about assuming that allowance hasn't been set is that `require(allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= _tokenAmount);` statement right before the transfer -- in both versions.  This should mean allowance really has been set, or the operation would revert.